# xsl transform help remove a certain tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given this portion of an xml, i need to remove any tag that has `xsi:nil="true"`

I'm currently using this XSL to remove the blank nodes as well so need to retain that as well. Attached below. Thanks.

XML:

```
<ns1:EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ns1:AnnualOfferOfCoverageCd>1G</ns1:AnnualOfferOfCoverageCd>
  <ns1:AnnlShrLowestCostMthlyPremAmt xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns1:MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
    <ns1:JanuaryAmt>0</ns1:JanuaryAmt>
    <ns1:FebruaryAmt>0</ns1:FebruaryAmt>
    <ns1:MarchAmt>0</ns1:MarchAmt>
    <ns1:AprilAmt>0</ns1:AprilAmt>
    <ns1:MayAmt>0</ns1:MayAmt>
    <ns1:JuneAmt>0</ns1:JuneAmt>
    <ns1:JulyAmt>0</ns1:JulyAmt>
    <ns1:AugustAmt>0</ns1:AugustAmt>
    <ns1:SeptemberAmt>0</ns1:SeptemberAmt>
    <ns1:OctoberAmt>0</ns1:OctoberAmt>
    <ns1:NovemberAmt>0</ns1:NovemberAmt>
    <ns1:DecemberAmt>0</ns1:DecemberAmt>
  </ns1:MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
</ns1:EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|SDLT">
    <xsl:if test="count(descendant::text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) &gt; 0] | @*[string-length(.) &gt; 0])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty far. Replace the namespace URI for `ns1` with the proper value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you'd have to add namespaces to your XML as well as your XSLT like

```
xmlns:xsi="http://some.thing" and xmlns:ns1="some.other.thing"
```

you'd just have to add the following line to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />
```

Without namespaces, you could omit the 'xsi:' from the above expression.

Result:

```
<ns1:EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp xmlns:xsi="http://some.thing" xmlns:ns1="some.other.thing">
    <ns1:AnnualOfferOfCoverageCd>1G</ns1:AnnualOfferOfCoverageCd>
    <ns1:MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
        <ns1:JanuaryAmt>0</ns1:JanuaryAmt>
        <ns1:FebruaryAmt>0</ns1:FebruaryAmt>
        <ns1:MarchAmt>0</ns1:MarchAmt>
        <ns1:AprilAmt>0</ns1:AprilAmt>
        <ns1:MayAmt>0</ns1:MayAmt>
        <ns1:JuneAmt>0</ns1:JuneAmt>
        <ns1:JulyAmt>0</ns1:JulyAmt>
        <ns1:AugustAmt>0</ns1:AugustAmt>
        <ns1:SeptemberAmt>0</ns1:SeptemberAmt>
        <ns1:OctoberAmt>0</ns1:OctoberAmt>
        <ns1:NovemberAmt>0</ns1:NovemberAmt>
        <ns1:DecemberAmt>0</ns1:DecemberAmt>
    </ns1:MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
</ns1:EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
```